# Imagemagik Issue creating a bitmap image with a layered SVG

Tags: svg, imagemagick, inkscape

We have an issue with creating an image with an SVG that we can’t seem to solve. We would greatly appreciate any help to get this sorted or learn if this is a bug in Imagemagik which has no solution.

So we are creating a bitmap image by layering an SVG on top of a jpg image. When we do this what happens is that the SVG gets distorted or displaced from the centre as it should be. When we create an image by layering a png on top of a jpg everything works correctly. It is just when using an SVG image that the problem happens.

```
 magick -size 654x508 canvas:#ff0000 ( original.jpg -thumbnail 938x508 -page -142+0 ) ( -background transparent -density 300 original.svg -thumbnail 536x79! -page +59+214 ) -layers flatten
```

We are using ImageMagick 7.1.0-47 Q16-HDRI x86_64 d91623c12:20220827
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png raqm tiff webp x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (7.5)

Comment: Please click [edit] and share the minimum code and images to recreate the problem. Also state which **ImageMagick** version you are using. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the simplest SVG that exhibits the problem. Also, your command is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Did you click `Export PNG Image` or shortcut `Shift+Ctrl+E` and export the file format as .png? And make sure your image is inside the `Document Properties - Page` you provided.